# How to move folder position in vsts?

Tags: visual-studio-2013, azure-devops

In a legacy solution, all project folders was created inside "\BuildProcessTemplates" folder.

Than, we have:

\BuildProcessTemplates\Web

\BuildProcessTemplates\Consoles

\BuildProcessTemplates\Mobile

etc...

How do I put all project folders outside BuildProcessTemplates without causing problems with VSTS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the source control explorer in Visual Studio, right click each folder and choose "Move". You'll have to do one folder at a time.

Whether this causes "problems" or not depends on what you define as a "problem". Builds that are dependent on that path will break and have to be updated.

Comment: It worked perfectly. I was affraid of reference problems after the move command, but everything worked correctly. Thanks Daniel.